# Accessing a UserControl from different Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to use the already written code which accesses a control from an other control in the following code.

Controls_SearchFeaturedMerchants UCMerchant = (Controls_SearchFeaturedMerchants)this.Parent.FindControl("UCSearchFeaturedMerchants1");

I am wondering what this statement says. Can someone please give me some idea :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666607/accessing-an-object-on-usercontrol-from-another-usercontrol-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly here is the brief:

On a page (ContentPage) is hosting two user controls (UsrCtrl1, UsrCtrl2).

Now "UsrCtrl1" wanted to access some data in the "UsrCtrl2".

For that I'll write code like - "UsrCtrl1" parent is the "ContentPage" that page hosts "UsrCtrl2", so I'll first get the "UsrCtrl2" from the parent page with the following code:

`this.Parent.FindControl("UsrCtrl2Name")` -> **this** means current user control which is "UsrCtrl1" and **Parent** means is the "ContentPage" (it may be parent control or page) in that you are trying to find a contrl with Id "UsrCtrl2Name" (this is the id of the 2nd user control in the content page).

When you use FindContrl method it always returns base type UserControl and you need to cast it to your usercontrol in this case it is of type "UsrCtrl2".

I hope this is clear now.

Comment: The `FindControl()` function requires the id of the control, not the name. Also, `this.Parent` does not necessarily refer to the page but rather the parent control, which can be a page, panel, etc.

Comment: @Nimrod: Thanks, I edited it now. Parent in this example is ContentPage that's why I specifically mentioned that, anyway I added your point too. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in plain text it is saying:
Get the Parent Control of the current control and then find UCSearchFeaturedMerchants1 on said control.  Cast the result into a Controls_SearchFeaturedMerchants.

Hope that sums it up for you