# Accessing an object on userControl from another userControl c#

Tags: c#, object, static

I have this `userControl` which contains `ListBox`. I want to access that `ListBox` from another `userControl`.

For example:

```
UserControl1.ListBox1.Items.Count;
```

Comment: What is stopping you to do that?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - I can't access a list box. It just can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add A Public Property ItemsCount in your user control

```
public int ItemsCount 
{
    get { return ListBox1.Items.Count; }
}

or

public ListBox MyListBox 
{
    get { return ListBox1; }
}
```

to access the whole listbox

Answer (score 2):

Make a property of `ListBox` in your first `usercontrol` and get that like

```
public ListBox lstBox
{
  get { return this.listBox1;}
}
```

Now access the ListBox from other usercontrol like that

```
usercontrol1 obj = new usercontrol1();
int itemCount =  obj.lstBox.Items.Count ;
```